# Framer Motion with `layout` Prop Not Animating

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have an element in a certain grid column. When I click a button I want the element to move to a different column and have the movement be animated. Below is the relevant code.

```
const [textLocation, setTextLocation] = useState(1);

const moveText = () => {
  setTextLocation(textLocation + 1);
}

<div className="grid grid-cols-12">
  <motion.div layout className={`bg-red-300 col-start-${textLocation}`}>
    Text
  </motion.div>
</div>

<button onClick={moveText}>
  Move Text
</button>
```

According to the framer-motion documentation, if the `layout` property is set, any time the element's style changes, there should be an animation. In my case, I am using TailwindCSS to style my components and I am changing the column start position via `col-start-${textLocation}`.

The animation does not work but what is weird is that it animates correctly for SOME values of `col-start-{x}`. For example, `col-start-2` doesn't work, but `col-start-3` does. This doesn't seem to be consistent either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Surely too late, but if someone would need this, you cannot use `string` litterals with *tailwind*, `col-start-${textLocation}` would get you `col-start-3` for `textLocation = 3`, but *tailwind* will not process it.